# Can page heading marks work with paracol?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, scripts, paracol, parcolumns

**Problem summary:** Neither the standard marks nor `extramarks` work  as desired when using `paracol` because LaTeX treats each column as a separate page.  In my application, each page on paper consists of many "pages" in TeX.

**More background:** There appear to be multiple options for setting page marks, including the standard marks and the `\usepackage{extramarks}`.  According to online sources, such as the [`fix2col` package](http://ctan.mirror.ftn.uns.ac.rs/macros/latex/contrib/fix2col/fix2col.pdf), a scripted solution which I have vainly attempted using, since 2015 these problems should be fixed for `multicol` environments.   (Incidentally, I'm not sure whether my TeX is the 2014 or 2015 version.)  However, `paracol` seems unique, or perhaps my implementation of it is for a non-standard use, and I have searched in vain for any online solution to this. No question here appears to have addressed this issue previously, unless, perhaps, I simply need guidance as to the proper jargon to search under.

**Specific use:** I use `paracol` for a lexicon, and if, as I have read, each column represents a "page" in LaTeX, every actual page of my book would include many "pages."  With this, I have been forced to use the `\begin{samepage}...\end{samepage}` pragma, coupled with `\nopagebreak` to prevent some unwanted orphans/widows.  However, I want to have the header at the top of each page indicate the first and last word entries on that page; e.g. "Abiram - Absalom".  At present, I get only "Absalom."  This appears to be the result of a "bug" (design factor) with LaTeX, unless I'm making some silly mistake.

**Example:** Here's an example showing the first two pages of lexical entries.  Notice that the heading repeats the same word, and that the word may actually have fallen on the next page instead of the current one.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{extbook}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{wrapfig,graphicx,lipsum}    
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, total={210mm,297mm}, left=30mm,top=20mm, footskip=30pt, headsep=15pt, textwidth=160mm, textheight=260mm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{extramarks}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\center\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-35pt}{20pt}
\usepackage[toc]{multitoc}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{greek}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek, Renderer=AAT]{Gentium Plus}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew, Renderer=AAT]{Ezra SIL}
\widowpenalty=1000
\clubpenalty=10000
\raggedbottom
\setlength{\headheight}{16pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{2.5em}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % Default is 15pt.
\setlength{\baselineskip}{1.0em}   %single spacing
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.3in}  % left margin is 1.3in on right pages
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.4in} % .6in left margin for even pages, 2-sided document
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 1fil minus 6pt}

\setcolumnwidth{4cm,11cm}[2pt]
\setstretch{1.0}

\singlespacing

\newcommand{\mystrut}{\rule{0pt}{12pt}}

\newcommand{\mymarks}{
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\leftmark}{\rightmark}}
    {\rightmark} % if equal
    {\rightmark--\leftmark}} % if not equal
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\mymarks}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}
\renewcommand*{\multicolumntoc}{3}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}

 \setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}
 \newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage

\begin{paracol}{2}
\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Aaron\extramarks{Aaron}{Aaron}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} H175
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \texthebrew{אַהֲרוֹן} ʼAhărôwn, \texthebrew{}  a-har-one'; of uncertain derivation; Aharon, the brother of Moses:--Aaron. \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Aaron\extramarks{Aaron}{Aaron}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} G2
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \textbf{\textgreek{Ἀαρών}} Aarṓn, \textbf{\textgreek{}}  ah-ar-ohn'; of Hebrew origin (H175); Aaron, the brother of Moses:--Aaron. \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Aaronites\extramarks{Aaronites}{Aaronites}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} H175
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \texthebrew{אַהֲרוֹן} ʼAhărôwn, \texthebrew{}  a-har-one'; of uncertain derivation; Aharon, the brother of Moses:--Aaron. \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Abaddon\extramarks{Abaddon}{Abaddon}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} G3
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \textbf{\textgreek{Ἀβαδδών}} Abaddṓn, \textbf{\textgreek{}}  ab-ad-dohn'; of Hebrew origin (H11); a destroying angel:--Abaddon. \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Abagtha\extramarks{Abagtha}{Abagtha}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} H5
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \texthebrew{אֲבַגְתָא} ʼĂbagthâʼ, \texthebrew{}  ab-ag-thaw'; of foreign origin; Abagtha, a eunuch of Xerxes:--Abagtha. \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Abana\extramarks{Abana}{Abana}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} H71
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \texthebrew{אֲבָנָה} ʼĂbânâh, \texthebrew{}  ab-aw-naw'; perhaps feminine of H68; stony; Compare H549. Abanah, a river near Damascus:--Abana. \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Abarim\extramarks{Abarim}{Abarim}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} H5682
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \texthebrew{עֲבָרִים} ʻĂbârîym, \texthebrew{}  ab-aw-reem'; plural of H5676; regions beyond; Abarim, a place in Palestine:--Abarim, passages. \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Abba\extramarks{Abba}{Abba}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} G5
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \textbf{\textgreek{Ἀββᾶ}} Abbâ, \textbf{\textgreek{}}  ab-bah'; of Chaldee origin (H2); father as a vocative:--Abba. \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Abda\extramarks{Abda}{Abda}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} H5653
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \texthebrew{עַבְדָּא} ʻAbdâʼ, \texthebrew{}  ab-daw'; from H5647; work; Abda, the name of two Israelites:--Abda \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Abdeel\extramarks{Abdeel}{Abdeel}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} H5655
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \texthebrew{עַבְדְּאֵל} ʻAbdᵉʼêl, \texthebrew{}  ab-deh-ale'; from H5647 and H410; serving God; Abdeel, an Israelite:--Abdeel. Compare H5661. \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Abdi\extramarks{Abdi}{Abdi}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} H5660
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \texthebrew{עַבְדִּי} ʻAbdîy, \texthebrew{}  ab-dee'; from H5647; serviceable; Abdi, the name of two Israelites:--Abdi. \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Abdiel\extramarks{Abdiel}{Abdiel}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} H5661
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \texthebrew{עַבְדִיאֵל} ʻAbdîyʼêl, \texthebrew{}  ab-dee-ale'; from H5650 and H410; servant of God; Abdiel, an Israelite:--Abdiel. Compare H5655. \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Abdon\extramarks{Abdon}{Abdon}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} H5658
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \texthebrew{עַבְדוֹן} ʻAbdôwn, \texthebrew{}  ab-dohn'; from H5647; servitude; Abdon, the name of a place in Palestine and of four Israelites:--Abdon. Compare H5683. \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Abednego\extramarks{Abednego}{Abednego}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} H5664
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \texthebrew{עֲבֵד נְגוֹ} ʻĂbêd Nᵉgôw, \texthebrew{}  ab-ade' neg-o'; the same as H5665; Abed-Nego, the Babylonian name of one of Daniel's companions:--Abed-nego. \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Abednego\extramarks{Abednego}{Abednego}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} H5665
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \texthebrew{עֲבֵד נְגוֹא} ʻĂbêd Nᵉgôwʼ, \texthebrew{}  ab-ade' neg-o'; (Aramaic) of foreign origin; Abed-Nego, the name of Azariah:--Abed-nego. \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Abel\extramarks{Abel}{Abel}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} H1893
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \texthebrew{הֶבֶל} Hebel, \texthebrew{}  heh'-bel; the same as H1892; Hebel, the son of Adam:--Abel. \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Abel\extramarks{Abel}{Abel}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} H59
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \texthebrew{אָבֵל} ʼÂbêl, \texthebrew{}  aw-bale'; from H58; a meadow; Abel, the name of two places in Palestine.:--Abel. \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Abel\extramarks{Abel}{Abel}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} G6
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \textbf{\textgreek{Ἄβελ}} Ábel, \textbf{\textgreek{}}  ab'-el; of Hebrew origin (H1893); Abel, the son of Adam:--Abel. \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Abelbethmaachah\extramarks{Abelbethmaachah}{Abelbethmaachah}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} H62
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \texthebrew{אָבֵל בֵּית־מֲעַכָה} ʼÂbêl Bêyth-Măʻakâh, \texthebrew{}  aw-bale' bayth ma-akaw'; from H58 and H1004 and H4601; meadow of Beth-Maakah; Abel of Beth-maakah, a place in Palestine:--Abel-beth-maachah, Abel of Beth-maachah, \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Abelmaim\extramarks{Abelmaim}{Abelmaim}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} H66
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \texthebrew{אַבֵל מַיִם} ʼAbêl Mayim, \texthebrew{}  aw-bale' mah'-yim; from H58 and H4325; meadow of water; Abel-Majim, a place in Palestine:--Abel-maim. \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Abelmeholah\extramarks{Abelmeholah}{Abelmeholah}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} H65
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \texthebrew{אָבֵל מְחוֹלָה} ʼÂbêl Mᵉchôwlâh, \texthebrew{}  aw-bale' mekh-o-law'; from H58 and H4246; meadow of dancing; Abel-Mecholah, a place in Palestine:--Abel-meholah. \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Abelmizraim\extramarks{Abelmizraim}{Abelmizraim}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} H67
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \texthebrew{אָבֵל מִצְרַיִם} ʼÂbêl Mitsrayim, \texthebrew{}  aw-bale' mits-rah'-yim; from H58 and H4714; meadow of Egypt; Abel-Mitsrajim, a place in Palestine:--Abel-mizraim. \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Abelshittim\extramarks{Abelshittim}{Abelshittim}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} H63
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \texthebrew{אָבֵל הַשִּׁטִּים} ʼÂbêl hash-Shiṭṭîym, \texthebrew{}  aw-bale' hash-shit-teem'; from H58 and the plural of H7848, with the article inserted; meadow of the acacias; Abel hash-Shittim, a place in Palestine:--Abelshittim. \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Abez\extramarks{Abez}{Abez}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} H77
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \texthebrew{אֶבֶץ} ʼEbets, \texthebrew{}  eh'-bets; from an unused root probably meaning to gleam; conspicuous; Ebets, a place in Palestine:--Abez. \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Abi\extramarks{Abi}{Abi}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} H21
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \texthebrew{אֲבִי} ʼĂbîy, \texthebrew{}  ab-ee'; from H1; fatherly; Abi, Hezekiah's mother:--Abi. \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Abia\extramarks{Abia}{Abia}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} H29
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \texthebrew{אֲבִיָּה} ʼĂbîyâh, \texthebrew{}  ab-ee-yaw'; or prolonged אֲבִיָּהוּ ʼĂbîyâhûw; from H1 and H3050; father (i.e. worshipper) of Jah; Abijah, the name of several Israelite men and two Israelitesses:--Abiah, Abijah. \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Abia\extramarks{Abia}{Abia}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} G7
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \textbf{\textgreek{Ἀβιά}} Abiá, \textbf{\textgreek{}}  ab-ee-ah'; of Hebrew origin (H29); Abijah, the name of two Israelites:--Abia. \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Abiah\extramarks{Abiah}{Abiah}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} H29
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \texthebrew{אֲבִיָּה} ʼĂbîyâh, \texthebrew{}  ab-ee-yaw'; or prolonged אֲבִיָּהוּ ʼĂbîyâhûw; from H1 and H3050; father (i.e. worshipper) of Jah; Abijah, the name of several Israelite men and two Israelitesses:--Abiah, Abijah. \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Abialbon\extramarks{Abialbon}{Abialbon}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} H45
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \texthebrew{אֲבִי־עַלְבוֹן} ʼĂbîy-ʻalbôwn, \texthebrew{}  ab-ee-al-bone'; from H1 and an unused root of uncertain derivation; probably, father of strength (i.e. valiant); Abialbon, an Israelite:--Abialbon. \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Abiasaph\extramarks{Abiasaph}{Abiasaph}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} H23
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \texthebrew{אֲבִיאָסָף} ʼĂbîyʼâçâph, \texthebrew{}  ab-ee-aw-sawf'; from H1 and H622; father of gathering (i.e. gatherer); Abiasaph, an Israelite:--Abiasaph. \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Abiathar\extramarks{Abiathar}{Abiathar}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} H54
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \texthebrew{אֶבְיָתָר} ʼEbyâthâr, ab-yaw-thawr'; contracted from H1 and H3498; father of abundance (i.e. liberal); Ebjathar, an Israel-ite:--Abiathar. \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Abiathar\extramarks{Abiathar}{Abiathar}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} G8
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \textbf{\textgreek{Ἀβιαθάρ}} Abiathár, \textbf{\textgreek{}}  ab-ee-ath'-ar; of Hebrew origin (H54); Abiathar, an Israelite:--Abiathar. \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Abib\extramarks{Abib}{Abib}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} H24
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \texthebrew{אָבִיב} ʼâbîyb, \texthebrew{}  aw-beeb'; from an unused root (meaning to be tender); green, i.e. a young ear of grain; hence, the name of the month Abib or Nisan:--Abib, ear, green ears of corn (not maize). \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\pagebreak[3] 

    \begin{leftcolumn*} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut
    \begin{samepage} \textbf{Abida\extramarks{Abida}{Abida}}
    \nopagebreak\par\nopagebreak
    \footnotesize\hspace*{1.5cm} H28
    \end{samepage}
    \end{leftcolumn*}
    \nopagebreak
    \begin{rightcolumn} \parskip=0pt
    \normalsize \mystrut \texthebrew{אֲבִידָע} ʼĂbîydâʻ, \texthebrew{}  ab-ee-daw'; from H1 and H3045; father of knowledge (i.e. knowing); Abida, a son of Abraham by Keturah:--Abida, Abidah. \par
    \end{rightcolumn}

\lhead{\firstmark}
\rhead{\leftmark}

\pagebreak[2]   
     \smallskip

\end{paracol}{2}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: Perhaps this will need to be addressed in some other manner.  If the packages I have selected will not support the features I need, I would be happy to hear suggestions of other ways to accomplish the same thing.

Is `paracol` now a deprecated package?  It appears when it comes to discussion of this package here, the silence is deafening.  If there's a better package, please enlighten me.

What about `tabular`, `tabu`, or `tabularx`?  Would any of these be able to word wrap, size the table to the size of the entire document, and handle `multirow`?

And now I'm learning about `ltxtable` and `ltablex` as well.  Experimenting with them has so far yielded no better results than `paracol`--it just trades one set of problems for another set.

Comment: "Incidentally, I'm not sure whether my TeX is the 2014 or 2015 version" - maybe upgrading is an option? I might not solve this specific issue (maybe it does!) but in any case many other bug fixes and new features have been added to a lot of packages in the past 4 years.

Comment: Well, from the little research I've done, upgrading TeX is a royal pain, and it prevents one from ever upgrading previous packages.  Further, my OSX is old (10.8), and I don't wish to risk an incompatibility issue that left me with no TeX at all.